# BigQuery error: scalar subquery produced more than one element

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I encountered a problem where I was not able to parse a single JSON string into BigQuery and get it to show up correctly.

Here is the JSON string

```
{"id":"ae7001c0-8728-4b90-a6a2 3e137983b320",
 "seq":"20210315047",
 "branch_id":"liketea0410",
 "terminal_no":"liketea0410A",
 "subtotal_":60,
 "total":60,
 "qty_subtotal":2,
 "discount_subtotal":0,
 "items":
     [{"no":"10010002",
       "name":"drink_1",
       "current_qty":1,
       "current_price":25,
       "current_discount":0,
       "discount_name":"",
       "condiment":
           [{"condiment_id":"e66b9b19-ec8e-4371-b4a8-b490b3996fe9",
             "name":"test1",
              "price":0},
            {"condiment_id":"6ad55413-0706-4e74-b9a8-f6e6a7b8c2cf",
             "name":"test2",
             "price":0}]},
      {"no":"10010002",
       "name":"drink_2",
       "current_qty":1,
       "current_price":25,
       "current_discount":0,
       "discount_name":"",
       "condiment":
           [{"condiment_id":"c24188c0-3612-40d1-8bdf-0da423af94c2",
            "name":"test_3",
            "price":10},
            {"condiment_id":"a5adcc2a-7c75-421c-b680-ca9392dfae12",
            "name":"test_4",
            "price":0},
            {"condiment_id":"5446a39c-2eae-4217-bf9a-b77545552c1f",
             "name":"test_5",
             "price":0}]}
      ]}
```

In this Json string there are two orders and I wish to split them into 2 separate rows.

My expected result is

```
drink_name | condiment_1 | condiment_2 | condiment_3 | 
drink_1       test_1         test_2        null
drink_2       test_4         test_5        test_3
```

So far from my own test I was able to PRASE_JSON one string and get the result showing. But if i'm using a column that contains the same JSON then bigquery returns with the error. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider below query.

```sql
WITH sample_data AS (
  SELECT """
    -- put your json here
    """ json
)
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT JSON_VALUE(item, '$.name') drink_name,
         JSON_VALUE(cond, '$.name') condiment,
         offset + 1 AS offset
    FROM sample_data, 
  UNNEST (JSON_QUERY_ARRAY(json, '$.items')) item,
  UNNEST (JSON_QUERY_ARRAY(item, '$.condiment')) cond WITH offset
)  PIVOT (ANY_VALUE(condiment) AS condiment FOR offset IN (1, 2, 3));
```

**Query results**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I need! However, could you elaborate a bit on the offset part and the pivot part at the end? I'm a bit confused. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @JerryTai , kindly check below quick explanation. 
 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Mwx9qzCfkdG4GgxJ7A_xFM-il8AlN5OkL2ZTsgShgM8/edit?usp=sharing